# Dataset Write to a file

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, filestream

I've got a `DataSet` with `600K records`.
When I try to write those data to a `XML` file I get `OutOfMemoryException` always.
Below is how I write data at the moment. 

What is the **most memory efficient** way to do this?

```
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    WorkingDataset.WriteXml(output, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    using (FileStream outputFile = File.Create(FilePath))
    {
         using (GZipStream compressedStream = new GZipStream(outputFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
         {
        compressedStream.Write(output.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)output.Length);
         }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using a `MemoryStream` at all? Just write it directly to disk:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(FilePath))
{
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(outputFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        WorkingDataset.WriteXml(zipStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
}
```

Comment: is memory stream so bad? If I have a layer for database and another layer for the business logic responsible to save the files, how could I do it without the MemoryStreams?

Comment: @GustavoCardoso: If you've got a reason to use one, and you don't mind having the whole file in memory at a time, that's fine. But the OP was specifically looking for a memory-efficient approach, and had no need for a `MemoryStream`. Context is important

Comment: I see, that is true. He was getting a OutOfMemoryException. You propabily should be careful about how you use MemoryStreams. Anyway, thank you, @Jon.